# Right way to use Spring WebClient in multi-thread environment

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I have one question regarding **Spring Framework** `WebClient`

In my application I need to do many similar API calls, sometimes I need to change headers in the calls (Authentication token). So the question arises, what would be better of the two options:

1. **To create one WebClient for all incoming requests to MyService.class, by making it `private final` field, like code below:**

```java
private final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("https://another_host.com/api/get_inf")
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .build();
```

Here arises another question: is `WebClient` *thread-safe*? (because service is used by many threads)

2. **To create new WebClient for each new request incoming to service class.**

---

I want to provide maximum performance and to use it in the right way, but I don't know how `WebClient` works inside it, and how it expects to be used.

Thank you.

Comment: "WebClient for all incoming requests " --- do you mean "outgoing" requests?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Two key things here about `WebClient`:

1. Its HTTP resources (connections, caches, etc) are managed by the underlying library, referenced by the `ClientHttpConnector` that you can configure on the `WebClient`
2. `WebClient` is immutable

With that in mind, you should try to reuse the same `ClientHttpConnector` across your application, because this will share the connection pool - this is arguably the most important thing for performance. This means you should try to derive all `WebClient` instances from the same `WebClient.create()` call. `Spring Boot` helps you with that by creating and configuring for you a `WebClient.Builder` bean that you can inject anywhere in your app.

Because `WebClient` *is* **immutable** it *is* **thread-safe**. `WebClient` is meant to be used in a reactive environment, where nothing is tied to a particular thread (this doesn't mean you cannot use in a traditional Servlet application).

If you'd like to change the way requests are made, there are several ways to achieve that:

### configure things in the builder phase

```
WebClient baseClient = WebClient.create()
                                .baseUrl("https://example.org");
```

### configure things on a per-request basis

```
Mono<ClientResponse> response = baseClient.get()
                                          .uri("/resource")
                                          .header("token", "secret")
                                          .exchange();
```

### create a new client instance out of an existing one

```
// mutate() will *copy* the builder state and create a new one out of it
WebClient authClient = baseClient.mutate()
                                 .defaultHeaders(hdrs -> {hdrs.add("token", "secret");})
                                 .build();
```

Comment: Thank you for full explanation. Could you also provide link on the doc? (Usually in doc you find examples of usage, but I'd like to read more about under hood part.)

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client

Comment: Why should you reuse one webclient across whole app? You said about connection pool and that's why I wouldn't share it - let's say that your application depends on two remote services that you connect with web client. If one service will be down and you have no circuit breaker or something that would prevent you from calling dead service then you can use all your connections for connecting to the dead service and the whole app is dead, because you didn't separate it.

Comment: I never said you should have only one webclient for the whole app. I believe Reactor Netty's connection pool is clever enough and is l managing connection on a per host basis, so I don't understand how this would happen. In the meantime things changed in Spring Framework in the way we're managing HTTP resources - so please ask a new question and feel free to point me to it.

Comment: WebClient in multi-threaded environment is overwriting my URI. WebClient is init at class level in following manner

    private WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector((HttpClientOptions.Builder builder) -> builder.disablePool())).build();
Had to mutate it per-request level. Let me know if this is the right approach.

Comment: it doesn't look like it. Please ask a new question.

Comment: I have already
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129956/springboot-v2-0-0-m6-webclient-making-multiple-duplicate-http-post-calls
Please help!

Comment: Even mutation of WebClient didn't work, it's overwriting my URL

Comment: WebClient.Builder seems is not thread safe, then how to get WebClient? Here my questions if you would like to take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54136085/spring-boot-webclient-builder-bean-usage-in-traditional-servlet-multi-threaded-a

Comment: Whether you create a separate WebClient or not, by default it will use shared resources to pool your connections together. Just look at the code for HttpClient.create - it calls HttpResources.get() to get the global resources. Read my answer for why I don't recommend this for external API calls.

Answer (score 14):

From my experience, if you are calling an external API on a server you have no control over, don't use WebClient at all, or use it with the pooling mechanism turned off. Any performance gains from connection pooling are greatly outweighed by the assumptions built into the (default reactor-netty) library that will cause random errors on one API call when the remote host abruptly terminates another. Sometimes, you don't even know where the error occurred because the calls are all made from a shared worker thread.

I mistakenly used `WebClient` because the doc for `RestTemplate` said it would be deprecated in the future. In hindsight, I would go with regular HttpClient or Apache Commons HttpClient, but if you are like me and already implemented with WebClient, you can turn off the pooling by creating your WebClient  as follows:

```
private WebClient createWebClient(int timeout) {
    TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.newConnection();
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.from(tcpClient)
        .tcpConfiguration(client -> client.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, timeout * 1000)
            .doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(timeout))));

    return WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .build();
}
```

---

**Creating a separate WebClient does not mean that WebClient will have a separate connection pool**. Just look at the code for `HttpClient.create` - it calls `HttpResources.get()` to get the global resources. You could provide the pool settings manually but considering the errors that occur even with the default setup, I don't consider it worth the risk.

Comment: Correct as stated in DOC, Httpclient.create() gives a pooled resource. But am not able to get why a shared pool causes errors. Of course, if you are subscribing to the corresponding flux stream, it would be the job of the flux to handle erros right? Why would ask people not to use? its actually great to make concurrent non blocking multiple requests. The default requests per connection pool would be 500 anyways.

Comment: A random error cant happen just like that. Either the flux stream is not handled properly or some issue with your code. Unless specied what exactly causes it, this answer could be misleading. @rougou

Comment: @Deekshith Anand
Yes, I should clarify we are using blocking mode so not handling the flux stream in our code at all. The way the question was posed made me assume the OP also just wanted to make a blocking call from several request threads. In that case the only benefit you get is the connection pool, but if the destination server isn't expecting you to pool the connections you can end up with random errors, which is what we were seeing.

Comment: In a non-blocking application I agree WebClient is the preferred choice and what I use in a different project.