# Springboot v2.0.0.M6 WebClient making multiple duplicate HTTP POST calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using spring-boot version 2.0.0.M6.
I need to make async HTTP calls from spring-boot app say APP1 to another app (play framework) say APP2.
So if I need to make 20 distinct async calls from APP1 to APP2, APP2 receives 20 requests out of which few are duplicates, which means these duplicates replaced few distinct requests.
Expected:

```
api/v1/call/1
api/v1/call/2
api/v1/call/3
api/v1/call/4
```

Actual:

```
api/v1/call/1
api/v1/call/2
api/v1/call/4
api/v1/call/4
```

I am using spring reactive WebClient.

Below is the spring boot version in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M6'
    //springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven {url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"}
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath("se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2")


}
}
```

My WebClient init snippet

```
private WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector((HttpClientOptions.Builder builder) -> builder.disablePool()))
        .build();
```

My POST method

```
public <T> Mono<JsonNode> postClient(String url, T postData) {
    return Mono.subscriberContext().flatMap(ctx -> {
        String cookieString = ctx.getOrDefault(Constants.SubscriberContextConstnats.COOKIES, StringUtils.EMPTY);
        URI uri = URI.create(url);
        return webClient.post().uri(uri).body(BodyInserters.fromObject(postData)).header(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, cookieString)
          .exchange().flatMap(clientResponse ->
          {
              return clientResponse.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class);
          })
         .onErrorMap(err -> new TurtleException(err.getMessage(), err))
         .doOnSuccess(jsonData -> {
         });
    });
}
```

The code from where this postClient method is invoked

```
private void getResultByKey(PremiumRequestHandler request, String key, BrokerConfig brokerConfig) {

    /* Live calls for the insurers */
    LOG.info("[PREMIUM SERVICE] LIVE CALLLLL MADE FOR: " + key + " AND REQUEST ID: " + request.getRequestId());

    String uri = brokerConfig.getHostUrl() + verticalResolver.determineResultUrl(request.getVertical()) + key;
    LOG.info("[PREMIUM SERVICE] LIVE CALL WITH URI : " + uri + " FOR REQUEST ID: " + request.getRequestId());
    Mono<PremiumResponse> premiumResponse = reactiveWebClient.postClient(uri, request.getPremiumRequest())
            .map(json -> PlatformUtils.mapToClass(json, PremiumResponse.class));

    premiumResponse.subscribe(resp -> {
        resp.getPremiumResults().forEach(result -> {
            LOG.info("Key " + result.getKey());

            repository.getResultRepoRawType(request.getVertical())
                    .save(result).subscribe();
            saveResult.subscriberContext(ctx -> {

                MultiBrokerMongoDBFactory.setDatabaseNameForCurrentThread(brokerConfig.getBroker());
                return ctx;
            }).subscribe();
        });
    }, error -> {
        LOG.info("[PREMIUM SERVICE] ERROR RECIEVED FOR " + key + " AND REQUEST ID" + request.getRequestId() + " > " + error.getMessage());
    });

}
```

Had put logs at the end-point in the client code, can not see multiple requests at that point.

Probably it's a bug in WebClient where URI is getting swapped in multithreaded environment.

Tried mutating WebClient, still the URI  is getting swapped

Please help.

Git Repo added [github.com/praveenk007/ps-demo](http://github.com/praveenk007/ps-demo)

Comment: I don't think your code snippet compiles, as it's referring to unknown variables (like `saveResult`). In general, should first try to use the latest GA version (2.1.0), since this Milestone version is outdated. Also, making that code snippet simpler and reducing the noise (with database calls and other things) would help.

Comment: Tried upgrading springboot version to 2.1.0 but giving  noMethod error at runtime. Will need to check the docs. Meanwhile will make a separate project on GitHub to replicate this issue.

Comment: You can use the postClient code and call it from a loop by passing a dynamic url and some static post object if you are trying to replicate this issue. Run the loop like 20-25 times.

Comment: Could you please share your code or an example on a repo? because I don't have issues related with that.

Comment: @JonathanJohx Here is a repo of the isolated code. But cannot replicate the error here.

https://github.com/praveenk007/ps-demo

Answer (score 1):

I happend to have experienced similar problem:

When calling the same service (here marked as *ExternalService*) in parallel (webflux) sometimes the same request was being sent and the problem indeed seems to reside in Webclient.

The solution was in changing the way Webclient is being created.

**Before:**

Here *ExternalCall* is configured client which calls *ExternalService*. So the parallel execution here was of *internalCall* method. Note we pass *WebClient.RequestBodySpec* class to *ExternalCall* class

```
@Bean
ExternalCall externalCall(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {

    var exchangeStrategies = getExchangeStrategies();

    var endpoint = "v1/data";
    var timeout = 10000;
    var uri = "https://externalService.com/";

    var requestBodySpec = webClientBuilder.clone()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()))
            .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
            .build()
            .post()
            .uri(endpoint)
            .accept(TEXT_XML)
            .contentType(TEXT_XML);

    return new ExternalCall(requestBodySpec, uri, timeout);
}
```

Then within *ExternalCall* class I had had

```
private Mono<String> internalCall(String rq) {
    return requestBodySpec.bodyValue(rq)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .timeout(timeout, Mono.error(() -> new TimeoutException(String.format("%s - timeout after %s seconds", "ExternalService", timeout.getSeconds()))));
}
```

**After:**

We pass WebClient class to *ExternalCall*.

```
@Bean
ExternalCall externalCall(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {

    var exchangeStrategies = getExchangeStrategies();

    var timeout = 10000;
    var uri = "https://externalService.com/";

    var webClient = webClientBuilder.clone()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()))
            .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
            .build();


    return new ExternalCall(webClient, uri, timeout);
}
```

Now we specify RequestBodySpec within ExternalCall class:

```
private Mono<String> internalCall(String rq) {
    return webClient
            .post()
            .uri(endpoint)
            .accept(TEXT_XML)
            .contentType(TEXT_XML)
            .bodyValue(rq)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .timeout(timeout, Mono.error(() -> new TimeoutException(String.format("%s - timeout after %s seconds", "ExternalService", timeout.getSeconds()))));
}
```

**Conclusions**: So apparently the moment you create WebClient.RequestBodySpec instance matters. Hope that helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

Adding my few observations:

`webClient.get()` or `webClient.post()` always returns new `DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec` on every call on which `URI` being called and I think it does not look like `URI` getting swapped.

```
class DefaultWebClient implements WebClient {

..
    @Override
    public RequestHeadersUriSpec<?> get() {
        return methodInternal(HttpMethod.GET);
    }
    @Override
    public RequestBodyUriSpec post() {
        return methodInternal(HttpMethod.POST);
    }


..


    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> exchange() {
        ClientRequest request = (this.inserter != null ?
                initRequestBuilder().body(this.inserter).build() :
                initRequestBuilder().build());
        return exchangeFunction.exchange(request).switchIfEmpty(NO_HTTP_CLIENT_RESPONSE_ERROR);
    }

    private ClientRequest.Builder initRequestBuilder() {
        URI uri = (this.uri != null ? this.uri : uriBuilderFactory.expand(""));
        return ClientRequest.create(this.httpMethod, uri)
                .headers(headers -> headers.addAll(initHeaders()))
                .cookies(cookies -> cookies.addAll(initCookies()))
                .attributes(attributes -> attributes.putAll(this.attributes));
    }
..
}
```

and `methodInternal` method looks like below

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private RequestBodyUriSpec methodInternal(HttpMethod httpMethod) {
    return new DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec(httpMethod);
}
```

In addition while making actual request also, new `ClientRequest` is created.

Class source

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/DefaultWebClient.java