# Is it wise to create Webclient again and again in Webflux since my base URI is not fixed?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

In my MicroService I have to fetch data from places. Some of the URL's are fixed but some are not . So do I need to create `WebClient` *again and again* if my base URL changes. If not then is the below way correct to create `WebClient`.

`WebClient.create();` and later is changing the `URI` *again and again* whenever I make a call. As per my understanding creating a `WebClient` must be some heavy operation.

```java
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                options -> options.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, requestTimeout).compression(true)
                        .afterNettyContextInit(ctx ->  ctx.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))));
        return WebClient.builder()
                        .clientConnector(connector)
                        .baseUrl(hostURL)
                        .build();
```

Comment: There's an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49107545/10264430

Comment: thanks @AlexanderPankin But found it after posting it here :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right way to use Spring WebClient in multi-thread environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095366/right-way-to-use-spring-webclient-in-multi-thread-environment)

Comment: @BrianClozel My problem is a bit different . My base URI is going to change most of the time.Explanation provided would still be valid in that case.

Comment: I am creating ReactorClientHttpConnector for every request. and passing it to WebClient.create().clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector ).baseURL("new URL ").build()

Answer (score 27):

`WebClient` instances are meant to be reusable. The only reason you'd need to have different client instances is for specific needs: instrumentation for observability, specific authentication client filters, specific connection/read/write timeouts.

Different base URIs is not a strong reason to create different instances. It's perfectly fine to create an instance and not set a base URI, it's merely a convenience to avoid duplication when calling the same host over and over again.

This is perfectly fine:

```java
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                               .build();

Mono<Resource> resource = webClient.get()
                                   .uri("http://example.org/resource")
                                   .retrieve()...;

Mono<Project> project = webClient.get()
                                 .uri("http://spring.io/projects/spring-boot")
                                 .retrieve()...;
```

Note that if you use `Spring Boot`, you should instead consider building your `WebClient` instance using the provided `WebClient.Builder` (see [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#io.rest-client.webclient) section for more details).

Comment: So the only thing to keep in mind if I am taking control over HTttpConnector then I need to use same instance across the application

Comment: You can set it I’m on the webclient builder just like in your sample.