# In a Spring Cloud Gateway server, is it necessary to build a WebClient for sending request manually?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

If I want to send some request to a microservice under the gateway (for example, trigger by a timer), should I build a new WebClient, or just use an existing bean?

Comment: WebClient is thread-safe, so it is an appropriate method to use WebClient as a bean. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095366/right-way-to-use-spring-webclient-in-multi-thread-environment).

Comment: Should I build a WebClient bean by myself, or could I just use some client/handler bean provided by Spring Cloud Gateway?

Comment: Like all the other beans, you have to create an instance of WebClient as a bean in your spring configuration. it seems like below. This is, of course, a simplified example and various properties can be set when creating a WebClient.
`@Configuration public class WebClientConfig {  
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.create();
    }
}`